# What does this distinctBy method?

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning `Kotlin`. Help me understand one moment. As I know `distinct` returns only unique values. So if we have the same value twice or more, it will return only one time. Correct me if I'm wrong.
But what does this `distinctBy` method? As I understand it has to return unique values according to my predicate.

I have  code like this:

```
fun main() {
val myList = listOf(5, 2, 9, 12, 5, 2)
myList.distinctBy { it > 10 }.forEach { println(it) }
```

So it has to return 12 imho, but I'm getting an output: 5, 12. But why?

Answer (score 3):

`distinctBy` takes a selector, not a predicate. It is usually used for objects, where you want a distinct based on a particular field. An example:

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(
        Pojo(1, "abc"),
        Pojo(2, "xyz"),
        Pojo(1, "hello"),
        Pojo(1, "world")
    )
    list.distinctBy { it.fizz }.forEach { println(it) }
}

data class Pojo(
    val fizz: Int,
    val buzz: String
)
```

This will return a distinct on the `fizz` property.

```
Pojo(fizz=1, buzz=abc)
Pojo(fizz=2, buzz=xyz)
```

If you want to use a predicate, you should use something like `filter`.

```
val myList = listOf(5, 2, 9, 12, 5, 2, 13, 12)
myList.filter { it > 10 }.forEach { println(it) }
```

This will print:

```
12
13
12
```

As you can see, `filter` will not give you an unique list. You can do that by calling `toSet()` on your list before the filter (and it will still be a `List` after the filter). Or by calling `distinct()` after the filter. The `distinct()` will actually just create a `Set` and turn it back on into a `List`, so I'd suggest to just use `toSet()` before the filter.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation)

Comment: @HaykMkrtchyan np, I've also changed the last note as well. It should be better now.

Answer (score 2):

`distinctBy` is using selector against objects in the list will be distinguished. This is rarely used for primitives. In your case, creates two-keys map, for keys true and false, and only first two values will be mapped.

I presume you want to filter out all numbers greater than 10, you must use `.filter { it > 10 }` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Returns a list containing only elements from the given collection
> having distinct keys returned by the given [selector] function.

You are getting `5 12` as output because what you have done is similar to:

```
val myList = listOf(5, 2, 9, 12, 5, 2)
val set = HashSet<Boolean>()
val list = ArrayList<Int>()
for (e in myList) {
    if (set.add(e>10)) {
        list.add(e)
    }
}
list.forEach { println(it) }
```